# I'm am trying to check to see if a variable is empty or not in C

Tags: c

I have a variable that is going to store a -1 and if not a -1 then a 1, but before I store the 1 I want to check the variable for NaN. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int someVar;

  if (some condition)
     someVar = -1;
  else if((someVar == NaN) && (some other condition))
     someVar = 1;

  return 0;
}
```

Will the first condition return `true` in the else if statement if there is nothing stored in `someVar`?

Comment: What do you mean by empty?

Comment: `someVar` is uninitialized so you have no idea what the value is. You should **always** initialize variables before reading them.

Comment: No. Reading (non-static, non-global) uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour.

Comment: C does not have a concept of "empty" variables. Trying to do just about anything with a variable you didn't initialize (including check its value) is undefined behavior; anything could happen, including things that make absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Comment: (The standard hyperbole is that the compiler is free to [make demons fly out your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) if you do this.)

Comment: One *could* look at non-void null-pointer like something identifying some other thing as being "*empty*" or "*not around*", namely an instance of the pointer's type, where it would point to if not being a null-pointer.

Comment: @user2357112 Wow, that's actually super comical. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable resides in RAM. RAM is never empty. Each cell has a value. Either the value is known by the programmer or not, depends whether the programmer has initialized that variable or not.

I know two ways of signaling the "emptyness" of a variable. One is to have a value that means "empty", like "0", or MAX_INTEGER, or whatever you like. This works if the logic of your algorithm imposes your variable to have only certain values, so you can know when the value is valid or not. If not, you can say the variable is not valid, or empty.

If your variable can hold any value (within the limits of your type), then a solution may be to use a small struct, like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int value;
  int is_empty;
} tVar;
```

So declaring variable `i` this way...

```
tVar i;
```

You can initialize as empty, like this:

```
i.is_empty = 1;
```

So, your program becomes:

```
int main( void )
{
  tVar someVar = {0,1};  // declaring and initializing it as empty

  ...
  ...
  ...    
  if (!someVar.is_empty) // if someVar is not empty...
  {
     someVar.value = -1;
     someVar.is_empty = 0; // is not empty any more
  }
  else if (someVar.is_empty && (some_other_condition))
  {
     someVar.value = 1;
     someVar.is_empty = 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being so thorough!

Answer (score 3):

A variable cannot be "empty." It always has a value.

You can manually specify a value, which indicates "emptiness" as done with strings: a null byte (with the value `0`) indicates the end of the string. Here, it's not emptiness per se but you get what I mean, hopefully.

Because a variable cannot be empty, there is no common NaN value for it; every value is a number, so NaN (not a number) does not make sense.
The floating-point format IEEE 754 supports NaN values but that is only possible because certain values of floating-point numbers have been assigned that meaning.

Comment: NMDV, but "A variable cannot be "empty." is not so.  It isn't that a variable cannot be empty, it is that in C, code has no defined way to detect it.  C hints at this with _indeterminate value_: either an unspecified value or a trap representation.  IOWs, a variable _could_ have an _empty_ state.  Many architectures do not employ this.

Comment: @chux OK, if we think about a variable as an abstract container for data, then yes, you're right. I was rather referring to a memory location, which is always occupied with a value, but that's a bit imprecise, agreed.

Comment: Not so abstract: A memory location may not always have an accessible value.  An integer is made of of sign, value & padding bits.  Not all value/sign combinations are valid.  1) integer type written at program start with all bit zeros (sign, value bits, padding) & padding bits are an error correction code or parity. Reading that as an `int` would generate a fault.  2) 2's complement system with `INT_MIN == -2147483647` and `-2147483648` "value" as a trap. `int`could have the trap "value", but reading it causes a fault. 3) Other scenarios possible, C supports them.

Comment: @chux ... which are all examples of interpretation. If we consider a memory location without any abstraction, i.e., interpretation, it cannot be empty. If you have an example with the barest definition of "memory location" possible, which **does** have some value indicating a different state like "emptiness," I'll budge.

Comment: Your comment was "Downvoter Some elaboration is appreciated".  Although not my DV, my explanation points out why your answer is incorrect  with "It always has a value". Yes memory bits are 0 or 1, but the C implementation determines what is a _value_ and what is _empty_.   You do not agree.  Perhaps that is why the DVer did not explain - not worth the [agro](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=agro+or+aggro).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have "nothing" stored in variable. Every variable has value.
In most cases there will be stored "0", but in not-so-rare cases you will have some garbage stored in your Variable. Its something that's just left there just before your Variable got it's place in memory (the one where 'garbage' is).

The 'NaN' you get in some other cases, like dividing by zero, and something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You always have a value to a variable. If you didn't store anything in it, It stores a random number which often called "Garbage", and we want to avoid it. So you can't check if a variable is empty, because it never will be.